# Вставить / обновить значения в столбце postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Всем привет!
Имеется 2 таблицы. Необходимо из первого столбца таблицы №2 вставить значения во второй столбец таблицы №1. Никакой логики при вставке нет. Подскажите, как правильно будет осуществить вставку (желательно без процедур)?  Язык **PostgreSQL 8.3**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В таком случае создаются новые строчки

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, записи в таблице 1 сортированы строго по возрастанию column_1. Так вот - для установления соответствия **необходимо** формулирование критерия сортировки записей в таблице 2, которая обеспечит точно требуемый порядок записей. И, если порядок по таблице 1 должен быть иным - то и для неё необходим такой критерий сортировки.

Comment: *Необходимо из первого столбца таблицы №2 вставить значения во второй столбец таблицы №1.* Это не "вставить из таблицы 2 в таблицу 1" (что делает INSERT), а "обновить записи таблицы 1 значениями из таблицы 2" (что делает UPDATE).

Comment: @Akina Записи в 1 таблице могут быть не отсортированы. Необходимо обновить  столбцы 1 таблицы, где колонка №2 принимает значения из таблицы №2 колонки №1. Никаких условий для обновления нет.

Comment: *Необходимо обновить столбцы 1 таблицы, где колонка №2 принимает значения из таблицы №2 колонки №1* Как, в каком порядке, как определить, значение из какой записи таблицы 2 должно попасть в заданную запись таблицы 1? PS. А количество записей в таблицах хотя бы совпадает?

Comment: @Akina Любой порядок значений. В первой таблице 1 млн записей, во второй таблице 3 млн записей. Т.е. в 1 таблицу должны вставиться 1 млн записей из второй таблицы. Была идея использовать **LIMIT 1000000**

Answer (score 0):

Для затравки.

Копирование записей из таблицы 2 в таблицу 1 так, что каждое значение из таблицы 2 попадает в случайную запись таблицы 1. Если в таблице 1 записей больше, некоторые её записи останутся необновлёнными, если меньше, то часть значений из таблицы 2 никуда не попадёт.

```sql
WITH 
cte1 AS ( SELECT column_1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RANDOM()) rn 
          FROM table1 ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT column_1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RANDOM()) rn 
          FROM table2 )
UPDATE table1
SET column_2 = ( SELECT cte2.column_1
                 FROM cte2
                 JOIN cte1 ON cte1.rn = cte2.rn 
                 WHERE cte1.column_1 = table1.column_1 );
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c05cad6177b43a4904d013e3d8a82ac5)

Суть происходящего - записи в обеих таблицах нумеруются (в случайном порядке), затем выполняется обновление на основании равенства присвоенных номеров.

Comment: Забыл уточнить, что версия PostgreSQL 8.3. Там отсутствует возможность работы через табличные выражения WITH, к сожалению.

Comment: @Phil *Забыл уточнить, что версия PostgreSQL 8.3.* Добавьте в самое начало вопроса, да пожирнее. Впрочем, на суть это не влияет. Нет нумерации? используйте generate_series().

Comment: Нумерация есть. Ошибка возникает **ERROR: syntax error at or near "UPDATE"**

Comment: @Phil https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=cf82a7d05f67912a1de95f65198f17f8

Comment: Теперь возникает ошибка **ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression**

Comment: Видимо рандом выбирает одинаковые значения

Comment: Ну попробуй убрать рандомную сортировку - тут. походу. оптимизация косячит. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c79bc0ba2fb5aa7f092d695c7046fa80

Comment: UPDATE table1
SET column_2 = ( SELECT cte2.column_1
                 FROM ( SELECT column_1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () rn 
                        FROM table2 )cte2
                 JOIN ( SELECT column_1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () rn 
                        FROM table1 ) cte1 ON cte1.rn = cte2.rn 
                 **WHERE cte1.column_1 = table1.column_1 );** --на этоп этапе возникает ошибка **ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression**

Comment: @Phil Значит, в данных есть дубликаты. Я не зря долго и упорно твердил о сортировке, правда не добавив, что ключ такой сортировки должен быть уникальным. При полных и неразличимых дублях задача на текущих версии и структуре данных - нерешаема.

Comment: Спасибо Вам за помощь!